# disable expand/collapse in jstree

Tags: jstree

I have a requirement to show a JSTree but without expand and collapse. Is there any way to achieve this ?

In the below  link its mentioned that disabling expand and collapse is not available in jstree, its a bug it seems.

https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/jstree/DFWEmFZ4OeI

but its posted on 2009. So is this bug resolved?

Answer (score 0):

Just don't give the expand/collapse element space:

```
<style>
     .jstree ins {width:0px}
</style>
```

Comment: Thanks for quick reply .... 
Can you please tell where do i need set the width in case of below jstree ? 
$(function () { 
    $("#divCPTree").jstree({ 
       "themes":{ 
          "theme": "default", 
           "icons": false }, 
     json_data: { data: treeModel }, 
plugins: ["themes", "json_data", "ui"] 
}) 
});
It will better if you can give one sample JSTree

Thanks Once again

Comment: Just include the CSS style in same html file as where your tree goes.